# Numeric value of expression

Tags: probability, summation

$$1+3^k\binom{30}k + 3^{30}$$

No idea how to approach these type of problems.
Yes it is a summation from k values 0-30.

Comment: What range does k have here?  Does it go from 0 to 30, 1 to 30, or something else?

Comment: What do you need to do with these numbers? Add from $k=0$ to $30$? Then the Binomial Theorem will be useful.

Comment: I texified what you wrote, but I suspect that you’re missing a summation, as in Marvis’s answer; please let us know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your summation is
$$1 + \left(\sum_{k=1}^{29} \dbinom{30}k 3^k \right) + 3^{30}$$
If so, look up [binomial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem). We have
$$(x+y)^n = x^n + y^n + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \dbinom{n}kx^{n-k}y^k$$
In your case, $x=1$, $y=3$ and $n=30$. Hence,
$$1 + \left(\sum_{k=1}^{29} \dbinom{30}k 3^k \right) + 3^{30} = (1+3)^{30} = 4^{30} = 1152921504606846976$$